# Spritebatch.Begin() Transform Matrix

Tags: xna

I have been wondering for a while about how the transform matrix in spriteBatch is implemented. I've created a 2D camera, and the transform matrix is as follows:

```
            if (needUpdate)
            transformMatrix =
               Matrix.CreateTranslation(-Position.X, -Position.Y, 0) *
                Matrix.CreateScale(curZoom, curZoom, 1) ; needUpdate = false;
```

The camera works as good as I want, but I just want to know how the transformation is applied: Does the transformation only affects the axis of the sprites, or the screen co-ordinates too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After a bit of more research I came across this: ""The Transformation Matrix simply moves the world to that specific position, draws it and that’s it. Your objects still keep their positions.""
This line is what I've been looking for!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see you've answered your own question, but to provide complete information - `SpriteBatch` provides a similar interface to the traditional world-view-projection system of transformations.

The `SpriteBatch` class has an implicit **projection** matrix that takes coordinates in the "client space" of the viewport ((0,0) at the top left, one unit per pixel) and puts them on screen.

The `Begin` call has an overload that accepts a transformation matrix, which is the equivalent of a **view** matrix used for moving the camera around.

And the `Draw` call, while not actually using a matrix, allows you to specify position, rotation, scale, etc - equivalent to a **world** matrix used for positioning a model in the scene (model space to world space).

So you start with your "model" equivalent - which for `SpriteBatch` is a quad (sprite) of the size of the texture (or source rectangle). When drawn, that quad is transformed to its **world** coordinates, then that is transformed to its **view** coordinates, and then finally that is transformed to its **projection** coordinates.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! That really cleared up all the mess I had in my mind! Thanks again!!!