# XNA: Scrolling A Linearly Wrapped, Rotating Texture, Up, Down, Left, And Right:

Tags: c#, image, xna, scroll, xna-4.0

I'm working on a simple XNA based game for the PC where I have a game screen window size of 1024 X 768 and I want to scroll, in the direction in which I move my mouse, a linearly wrapped, rotating texture, which is 1280 X 1280 in size.

The origin of this texture has been set to it's center point(640, 640) and I then place this texture onscreen in the middle of my game window at (512, 384).

The code I have so far (pasted in it's entirety below) works perfectly until I introduce rotation to the mix.

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{

    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    int x;
    int y;

    float z = 250f;

    Texture2D Overlay;

    Texture2D RotatingBackground;

    Rectangle? sourceRectangle;

    Color color;

    float rotation;

    Vector2 ScreenCenter;

    Vector2 Origin;

    Vector2 scale;

    Vector2 Direction;

    SpriteEffects effects;

    float layerDepth;

    public Game1()
    {

        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1024;

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 768;

        graphics.ApplyChanges();

        Direction = Vector2.Zero;    

        IsMouseVisible = true;

        ScreenCenter = new Vector2(graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 2, graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight / 2);

        Mouse.SetPosition((int)graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 2, (int)graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight / 2);

        sourceRectangle = null;

        color = Color.White;

        rotation = 0.0f;

        scale = new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f);

        effects = SpriteEffects.None;

        layerDepth = 1.0f;

        base.Initialize();

    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        Overlay = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Overlay");

        RotatingBackground = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Background");

        Origin = new Vector2((int)RotatingBackground.Width / 2, (int)RotatingBackground.Height / 2);

    }


    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {

    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        float timePassed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        MouseState ms = Mouse.GetState();

        Vector2 MousePosition = new Vector2(ms.X, ms.Y);

        Direction = ScreenCenter - MousePosition;

        if (Direction != Vector2.Zero)
        {

            Direction.Normalize();

        }

        x += (int)(Direction.X * z * timePassed);

        y += (int)(Direction.Y * z * timePassed);


        //No rotation = texture scrolls as intended, With rotation = texture no longer scrolls in the direction of the mouse. My update method needs to somehow compensate for this.         
        //rotation += 0.01f;  

        base.Update(gameTime);

    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, SamplerState.LinearWrap, null, null);

        spriteBatch.Draw(RotatingBackground, ScreenCenter, new Rectangle(x, y, RotatingBackground.Width, RotatingBackground.Height), color, rotation, Origin, scale, effects, layerDepth);

        spriteBatch.Draw(Overlay, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);

    }
}
```

For example if I were to rotate the texture to the right then moving the mouse straight up from the screen's center causes the texture to scroll diagonally upwards and to the right - this is not my intent - If I move my mouse in any direction I want my texture to scroll in that direction just the same as if I had never introduced rotation to the mix.

How do I go about altering my Update() method to achieve this?

Thanks for reading.....

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I gather that you want the mouse to control the camera, and the rotation to affect only the texture.
For that, the change required affects the Draw method. When calling Spritebatch.Begin you should pass a transformation matrix as a parameter, using the x and y values. This allows you to rotate the texture in world coordinates, while moving the camera independent from the rotation.

Check this question - [Spritebatch.Begin() Transform Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403543/spritebatch-begin-transform-matrix) - to understand how the transform matrix works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Elideb. All my 'camera' consists of is a rectangle which is displaying part of my 1280 X 1280 linearly wrapped texture. I might be wrong, but I don't believe that I need a transformation matrix to do what I want as the code I've posted works fine until I introduce rotation of the texture around its origin. I need to adjust the x and y values somehow to compensate for the rotational movement. For example - If I move my mouse horizontaly to the left I want my texture to scroll left while rotating around its origin.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. There might be a more elegant solution, but it was sure a neat problem to solve.

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{

    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    int x;
    int y;

    float z = 250f;

    Texture2D Overlay;

    Texture2D RotatingBackground;

    Rectangle? sourceRectangle;

    Color color;

    float rotation;

    Vector2 ScreenCenter;

    Vector2 Origin;

    Vector2 scale;

    Vector2 Direction;

    SpriteEffects effects;

    float layerDepth;

    public Game1()
    {

        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1024;

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 768;

        graphics.ApplyChanges();

        Direction = Vector2.Zero;

        IsMouseVisible = true;

        ScreenCenter = new Vector2(graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 2, graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight / 2);

        Mouse.SetPosition((int)graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 2, (int)graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight / 2);

        sourceRectangle = null;

        color = Color.White;

        rotation = 0.0f;

        scale = new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f);

        effects = SpriteEffects.None;

        layerDepth = 1.0f;

        base.Initialize();

    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        Overlay = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Overlay");

        RotatingBackground = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Background");

        Origin = new Vector2((int)RotatingBackground.Width / 2, (int)RotatingBackground.Height / 2);

    }


    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {

    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        float timePassed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        MouseState ms = Mouse.GetState();

        Vector2 MousePosition = new Vector2(ms.X, ms.Y);

        Direction = ScreenCenter - MousePosition;

        if (Direction != Vector2.Zero)
        {

            float angle = 0;
            angle = (float)Math.Atan2(Direction.Y, Direction.X) - rotation;
            Direction.X = (float)Math.Cos(angle);
            Direction.Y = (float)Math.Sin(angle);
            Direction.Normalize();
        }

        x += (int)(Direction.X * z * timePassed);
        y += (int)(Direction.Y * z * timePassed);


        //No rotation = texture scrolls as intended, With rotation = texture no longer scrolls in the direction of the mouse. My update method needs to somehow compensate for this.         
        rotation += .01f ;
        if (rotation > MathHelper.Pi * 2)
        {
            rotation -= (MathHelper.Pi * 2);
        }
        base.Update(gameTime);

    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, SamplerState.LinearWrap, null, null);

        spriteBatch.Draw(RotatingBackground, ScreenCenter, new Rectangle(x, y, RotatingBackground.Width, RotatingBackground.Height), color, rotation, Origin, scale, effects, layerDepth);
        spriteBatch.Draw(Overlay, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);

    }
}
```