# Farseer Meter/Pixel Ratio

Tags: c#, xna, physics, xna-4.0, farseer

I've done a lot with box2d in c++, and am giving C# a try. It looks like Farseer is generally used in place of Box2D (I'm aware of Box2DXNA, but it seems a little outdated.) So, Farseer is what I've been using. When I was using C++ and Box2D, everyone always advised against using a 1pixel/meter ratio (For what reason, I don't know,) and usually suggested using somewhere around 30pixels/meter. As I've been researching Farseer, I've seen a lot of conflicting statements. Some say to use 1pixel/meter, others say to use a scale, others say to use ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits and ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits, etc.

So what should I use? Right now, I'm using ConvertUnits, but everything renders in weird places. Is there a de-facto standard or anything that I should go by? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you just use what makes sense? If a 2m high player is 20 pixels high, then the choice is obviously 10 pixels / meter

Comment: I think in your question you are using the word "pixels" where you should be using the word "units".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Farseer 3.x is based on Box2D. And the Box2D [FAQ says](http://code.google.com/p/box2d/wiki/FAQ#API):

> Box2D is tuned for meters-kilograms-seconds (MKS). Your moving objects should be between 0.1 - 10 meters. Do not use pixels as units! You will get a jittery simulation.

In other words, assuming a "normal" physics world, you should probably have **1 physics unit = 1m**. But any scale that causes the majority of your moving objects to be in the 0.1 to 10 unit range should be ok.

So, say you're making a model of a car. A really, *really* simple model that happens to be  a rectangle. You'd create it using something like:

```
float width = 4.1f; // average car length in meters
float height = 1.4f; // average car height in meters
// Note: this method takes half-sizes:
var carVertices = PolygonTools.CreateRectangle(width / 2f, height / 2f);
// Then pass carVertices into PolygonShape, etc...
```

The separate problem is how to then render your world at the correct size.

The way this is generally done is at render time using a camera or **view** matrix (in the standard world/view/projection system). The two places you could do this are `BasicEffect.View` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.basiceffect.view.aspx)), or the transformation matrix parameter to `SpriteBatch.Begin` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433701.aspx), [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403543/spritebatch-begin-transform-matrix/6406274#6406274)).

IMO, the Farseer `ConvertUnits` class is a very ugly way of handling the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I use int MetersPixel = 64; for all my base calcs. So i have little enemys that their textures are 16px wide. So when creating their bodys with Farseer the width is 0.25.

16 / 64 = 0.25

Most importantly the feel, size / scale and weight is right for my current game, i dont believe there is any golden rule or reason why you should have to jump through hoops just to make your code 10 = 1 etc.

Its working perfectly for me so far. I never thought to try convert 10px to 1m but with my current game build i would not see that as useful.