# MonoGame - Unit Convertion

Tags: xna, drawing, monogame, unit-conversion

I want to use my own Unit"system".
Something like 1 Pixel is equals to 0.01 Units.

Now when I want to draw something with my own Unitsystem, I always have to multiply/divide the value by 100.
I've found some answers that mentioned to use matrix in SpriteBatch.Begin, but I dont know how.

Could someone help me^^?

Answer (score 1):

Spritebatch.Begin()´s last parameter can be a transform matrix.

```
TransformMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(0.01);
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, null, null, null, TransformMatrix);
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I try to use a transform matrix the size of my textures is also affected. A 100*100 Texture would be scaled to the size of 1*1

Comment: OK, if you only wish to change your coordinates you can run that TransformMatrix on your Vectors. But I don't understand what you gain by this, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to use Farseer Physics in my Project. And in FarseerPhysics 1 Pixel is equal to 0.01 Units. The Exampleproject uses a ConvertUnit class to convert between the SimulationUnits and the DisplayUnits. I've also found a answer for this Problem, but I do not understand how I should use a BasicEffect or a ViewMatrix to solve my Problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733088/farseer-meter-pixel-ratio

Answer (score 0):

Farseer Physics provides a `ConvertUnits` class for this kind of thing. From memory the methods you're interested in are `ToSimUnits` and `ToDisplayUnits`. The [Farseer documentation](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/documentation) describes it like this:

```
// 1 meter = 64 pixels
ConvertUnits.SetDisplayUnitToSimUnitRatio(64f);

// If you object is 512 pixels wide and 128 pixels high:
float width = ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(512f) // 8 meters
float height = ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(128f) // 2 meters
```

> So the rules are:
>
> 1. Whenever you need to input pixels to the engine, you need to convert the number to meters first.
> 2. Whenever you take a value from the engine, and draw it on the screen, you need to convert it to pixels first.
>
> If you follow those simple rules, you will have a stable physics simulation.

On a related topic, you should look into [resolution independence](http://dylanwilson.net/resolution-independence-in-monogame-with-viewport-adapters).